# Regex pattern for postal codes

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern for 4 digits hyphen or space continued by 3 digits e.g.

```
1234 123
1234-123
```

I have tried this but it is not matching the requirements

```
^\\d{4}[-]{0,1}\\d{3}$
```

Comment: Use: `^\d{4}[ -]\d{3}$`

Comment: `[-]{0,1}` makes `-` optional but when a `-` is not there, you need a whitespace character and therefore you should use `[- ]` or `[\s-]` which means one of the characters from the square bracket i.e. a `-` or a whitespace character.

Answer (score 3):

Just include a space in the character class. If the hyphen or space is optional, add a `?` after it.

```
^\d{4}[ -]\d{3}$
```

Note that when using `String#matches`, you do not need to include the start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors.

```
System.out.println("1234-123".matches("\\d{4}[ -]\\d{3}")); // true
```

Comment: The hyphen/space appears to not be optional, at least according to the text description in the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Good catch.